# Automatically Mark ASP.NET MVC Website Deployment with Git Commit Hash ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I'm using git to manage my ASP.NET MVC project, which is deployed to Azure as Website periodically and manually.

Is there any method to identify the exact version (i.e. git commit hash id) of the website running on Azure after the deployment?

Comment: Can you clarify 'identify'? e.g. from the Portal, from a custom deployment script, from the runtime of your app?

Comment: Azure Cloud Service presents the last deployment day on Azure Management Portal,  whereas Azure Website doesn't. The runtime is a good approach, just like Bing: http://www.bing.com/version.aspx

Comment: Did you try going under Deployment Source for your web app is the Azure portal? You'll see the time and commit ID there.

Comment: Connecting Git on VSO to Azure works for smaller projects, this one is larger and our process doesn't allow me to check in credentials into git repo.

Comment: Your original question said you were deploying via git. Are you git pushing directly to the site? If so, you should see history under Deployment Source

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just use git to manage the code, but not the deployment. Instead I use VS'15 to publish the website to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Since you deploy via VS (hence using WebDeploy), the commit ID is simply not part of what's published.

I can think of two options:

The first is to make this part of your build system. i.e. at build time, write the commit to some file, and make sure this file gets deployed by VS.

The second is to use Kudu's deployment API (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#deployment) to add a history frame after you've deployed via VS. Look at the 'Add a deployment status to history' section in the wiki.